# Combining EmailStr with constr in pydantic 2.0

Tags: python, pydantic

we used pydantic's `EmailStr` and `ConstrainedStr` to standardize validation and transformation of email string in requests. It was done the following way:

```py
class EmailApiField(ConstrainedStr, EmailStr):
    to_lower = True
    strip_whitespace = True

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield from ConstrainedStr.__get_validators__()
        yield from EmailStr.__get_validators__()
```

and then it's used in our requests schemas definitions

```py
class LoginReq(SchemaBase):
    email: EmailApiField
```

Now, I can't find a way to achieve the same with pydantic 2.0. Anyone? :)

I tried the following

```py
EmailApiField = Annotated[
    EmailStr, BeforeValidator(constr(to_lower=True, strip_whitespace=True))
]
```

but `constr` cannot be used as `Annotated` metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly why applying the new [`StringConstraints`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/api/types/#pydantic.types.StringConstraints) metadata does not work properly with the [`EmailStr`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/api/networks/#pydantic.networks.EmailStr) type yet. I'll see if I can figure out, whether this is intentional or not.

In the meantime, luckily, your use case seems to be fairly simple, so I would suggest you just do the following:

```py
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator, EmailStr


def strip_and_lower(v: object) -> str:
    return str(v).strip().lower()


EmailApiType = Annotated[
    EmailStr,
    BeforeValidator(strip_and_lower),
]


class LoginReq(BaseModel):
    email: EmailApiType


print(LoginReq(email=" FoO@Bar.Baz "))  # email='foo@bar.baz'
```

Comment: ah, as simple as that <facepalm> :)